# Django rest framework - nested serializer - retrieve valid records of nested serializer and error for invalid

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am retrieving multiple client records at a time using "RegistrationSystemSerializer" serialize here.

```
class ClientRecordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    client_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField()

class RegistrationSystemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    count = serializers.IntegerField()
    results = ClientRecordSerializer(many=True)
```

If anytime anyone of client records is invalid then it is aborting entire process of extraction. i.e. suppose I have data like

```
{
"count" : 4,
"results":[
    {
   "client_id":"1234",
   "date_of_birth":"2012-02-06"
    },
    {
   "client_id":"2345",
   "date_of_birth":"2013-02-06"
    },   
    {
   "client_id":"4567",
   "date_of_birth":"2014-02-06"
    },   
    {
   "client_id":"1239",
   "date_of_birth":"06-02-2017"    # invalid date format
    },   
 ]
}
```

where "date_of_birth" of 4th client is in wrong format because a valid date can be only in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. If I apply above serialize in this data then it will not give me any data because one of the nested record do not satisfy criteria. What I want is to get all three valid nested records from serialize but error for the fourth one.

How to achieve the same using Django rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you need or not but you can try to override `to_internal_value` for deserializing and `to_representation` sor serializing processes.

This may looks something like this:

```
class ClientRecordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    client_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField()

     def to_internal_value(self, data):
         try:
             data = super(ClientRecordSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
             return data
         except:  
             return {'message': 'some error'}
```